# Не могу понять где ошибка. 2 одинаковых кода, один ООП, другой процедурный. Процедурный работает, ООП нет

Tags: php, mysql, unity3d

Переписываю процедурный код в ООП.
Столкнулся с проблемой очень странной... ООП код должен работать, но нет.. не работает.
Прошу вашей помощи в сравнении. Может я где то что то не так написал?
Вот оба кода - процедурный:

```
if(isset($_POST["loginUserEmail"])){ // Данные из поля 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["loginUserEmail"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["loginPassword"]);
    if($email != "" && $password != ""){
        //Check are entered username and password matched
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) > 0){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }else{
        echo "Оба поля обязательны.";
    }
}else{
    echo "Успешное соединение";
}
```

А это ООП который я написал:

```
if(isset($_POST["loginUserEmail"])) {
    
    $email = $_POST["loginUserEmail"];
    $password = $_POST["loginPassword"];

    if($email != "" && $password != "") {
        $accounts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', $email, $password);
        $accounts->numRows(); // Подсчитываем кол-во строк.
        
        if ($accounts->numRows() > 0) { // Больше 0 сообщаем 1, пускаем в игру
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }else{ echo "Оба поля обязательны.";}
}else { echo "Успешное соединение"; }
```

Что не так с моим кодом? Помогите пожалуйста. Может я в синтаксисе ошибся?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Настаиваю на том, чтобы вы смотрели на все ответы в теме про нахождения ошибок

Comment: Также в mysqli нет numRows, И уж точно не надо его два раза вызывать. Отсюда вывод: это НЕ 2 одинаковых кода

Comment: Тут дебагинг PHP не поможет. Через сайт скрипт ошибок не выдаёт. 
Я пробовал играться со строчкой if ($accounts->numRows() > 0), по разному. Загонял в переменную результат if ($var > 0) и т д п. Распечатывал результат выполнения функции $accounts = $db->query('SE...
Она работает и через сайт присылает значение 0 это проверено. 1 прислать не сможет так как форма находится в юнити2д, данные поступать должны оттуда.
И вот тут самое интересное... в процедурном коде они поступают, в ООП движок пишет в консоли NULL.

Comment: Именно поэтому я и спрашиваю профи в PHP что бы сравнили код и ткнули носом где я облажался, потому что у меня просто идей уже не осталось... код должен работать, а всё равно присылает NULL.

Comment: Эээ... Простите а где тут ООП? Вот если бы Вы создали модель формы авторизации, объявили бы там два поля `email` и `password`, реализовали бы метод `load()` в котором из `$_POST` заносили бы значения полей, реализовали бы метод `checkUserAccount` в котором бы проверяли в БД наличие такого аккаунта... И вызывали бы уже только методы этой модели - я бы согласился на ООП. А так я вижу практически идентичный хаотично написанный код. Уж простите за вольность мыслей. Попробуйте все же почитать что такое ООП и как им пользоваться.

Comment: у меня ещё не настолько много знаний к сожалению, что бы реализовать то что вы написали. Я пока только вот так могу, и то с какой то ошибкой, которую не могу идентифицировать.
ООП тут скорее стиль, чем суть =) Классы и методы я пока писать не научился, тем более такие сложные как регистрация-авторизация. Пишу как умею.
Надеюсь тут мне помогут сравнить код и выявить несоответствия.

Comment: "дебагинг PHP не поможет" --- а вы пробовали? Нет вы не пробовали. И не прочитали. ................. "скрипт ошибок не выдаёт" --- а вы настроили вывод ошибок? Нет не настроили. Почему? А потому что `numRows` в mysqli нет. А значит ошибка обеспечена..................... так что не надо придумывать что поможет, а что нет - прочитайте все способы нахождения ошибок для начала и попробуйте...........................и ещё раз скажу про numRows --- прочитайте документацию.Нет такого метода в таком виде...................."в ООП движок пишет в консоли NULL" --- включить отображение ошибок + отладка!

Comment: "а вы пробовали?" - Да пробовал. POST приходит из формы которая в движке юнити. И он не доходит.
"а вы настроили вывод ошибок?" - Нет не настраивал, я проверок навтыкал что бы понять какой пункт не работает. Может быть метод и деревянный, но сработал. То что из формы приходит NULL я узнал по крайней мере.
"А потому что numRows в mysqli нет"  Хм... серьёзно?
Вот часть кода из РАБОЧЕГО класса Database, через который я к БД коннекчусь.
``public function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $charset = 'utf8') {
  $this->connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);``

Comment: "в ООП движок пишет в консоли NULL" --- включить отображение ошибок + отладка!" NULL приходит не в консоли php. А в консоли движка Unity2D.
Из формы в движке, по дороге к бэкэнду php, теряется POST. При чём процедурный код работает с теми же запросами, и теми же ответами как из скрипта C# юнити, так и с бэкэнда php.

Comment: ""А потому что numRows в mysqli нет" Хм... серьёзно?" ----- вы бы в доки посмотрели, вместо того, чтобы удивляться................." Вот часть кода из РАБОЧЕГО класса Database," --- как он связан с numRows ?  Подсказка: **Никак** ............"То что из формы приходит NULL я узнал по крайней мере" --- тогда чего вы ожидаете от кода, если приходит NULL? ..................""а вы пробовали?" - Да пробовал" --- Нет не пробовали, потому что пользовались своим "деревянным способом".............." "а вы настроили вывод ошибок?" - Нет не настраивал" --- тогда удачи вам ещё десяток дней разбираться))

Comment: Я конечно разберусь, через десяток дней или позже, но разберусь... А вот вы ошиблись видимо топиком. Я просил помощи а не критики. 
И хватит писать идиотию... "А потому что numRows в mysqli нет"
Решистрация с этим же методом работает, и представьте себе с  numRows.
public function numRows() {
  $this->query->store_result();
  return $this->query->num_rows;
 }
Я даже метод вам покажу с которым она работает, а запрос query как это по вашему не странно... mysqli. Надо же... какая неожиданность. 
Ну и можете пойти уже... Я нашёл ответы на пхп.су благо там настоящие программисты есть.

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать: `numRows` в `mysqli` нет, а есть `num_rows`. что и описано внутри функции `numRows`, которая относится к реализации логики в классе DB. А сама она  имеет отношение к `mysqli `  ровно такое же, как балерина к стройке. Удачи в познавании.

Comment: Функция подсчёта строк в MySqli есть. И не надо тут затирать. Я сразу писал что эта функция есть. Вы же писали что её нет. Теперь понятен ваш уровень "познания".

Comment: Вася, я тебе написал про конкретную numRows (её **НЕТ**) а не num_rows (а вот **ОНА** есть). Умей правильно ЧИТАТЬ, то что другие пишут.